# Deploying Nuxt.js SSR app to production gives error

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have built a Universal app with Nuxt.js, and now I want to deploy it, however I am finding the process very confusing.

This is the scripts part of my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server/index.js",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
}
```

So far I have been using `npm run dev` with no problem. When I run `npm run build` it all seems to work fine, then when I run `npm run start` the app also runs succesfully, but it doesn't seem to be executing my recent *built* code, instead, it rather seems to be running the same dev code that was ran when doing `npm run dev`.

I have also tried to execute `nuxt start`, which made sense to run after executing `npm run build`, however the app crashes if I do so.

How do I run my SSR app in production after building it?
Is `npm run build` supposed to build any of my Node.js backend stuff?

This is my server/index.js

```
// Debug in development
process.env.DEBUG = 'nuxt:*'

require('dotenv').config()
const env = require('../config')
const express = require('express')
const consola = require('consola')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
const app = express()
const redis = require('./api/adapters/Redis')
const host = env.public.host
const port = env.public.port

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  next();
});

app.set('port', port)

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
let config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = !(env.public.environment === 'production')

async function start() {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  }

  // Connect to redis
  redis.connect()  // <-- This creates a connection with redis server, and doesn't seem to connect when running `nuxt start`, hence the error.
  require('fs').writeFile('ZZZ.txt', 'YES', 'utf8', () => {}) // <-- as an experiment ZZZ.txt file gets written when `npm run dev` but not when `nuxt start` is ran.

  // Handle errors
  process.once('uncaughtException', err => {
    redis.disconnect()
    process.exit(1)
  });

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render)

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host)
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  })
}
start()
```

Comment: can you add the error after you run nuxt start?

Comment: Show your server/index.js

Comment: @Tzelon the error I get is due to the fact that `redis.connect()`, doesn't seem to connect.

Comment: @Aldarund I have posted the server/index.js code, see the `redis.connect()` I believe this whole file is not being executed at all after `nuxt start`

Comment: If u do npm run build and then npm.run start it will use your builded files..u can check it by deleting .nuxt and try to run npm run start

Comment: @Aldarund yes it does, however it seems like the server/index.js is not being bundled. Is that supposed to be like that?

Comment: It's your entry point how it should be bundled? So yes it's supposed

Comment: @Aldarund Then it is not being bundled, that might be the issue. Why would that be the case?

Comment: How u want it yo be bundled? It's a file that is used by your command line. Also nuxt.confug not budnled as well as all used node modules

Comment: @Aldarund that is true. Then why `nuxt start` doesn't execute my server/index.js?

Comment: Because server/index is another thing at yo laucnh from nuxt start. It's a custom way. Nuxt start just use nuxt.config